# MongoDB E11000 duplicate key error collection (duplicate key error)

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, schema

I am trying to write an array to my mongodb and i keep getting this error...

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key
>   error collection: test.strains index: *id* dup key: { _id:
>   ObjectId('5ec18ebc5c7b4f6149499d93') }

adding to db

```
  const upsertStrain = async (strainObj) => {
    const DB_URL =
      "mongodb_url";

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState == 0) {
      mongoose.connect(DB_URL);
    }

    // if this strain exists, update the entry, don't insert
    let conditions = { name: strainObj.name };
    let options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };

    await Strain.findOneAndUpdate(
      conditions,
      strainObj,
      options,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      }
    );
  };
```

calling function

```
  for(strain of strains) {
    await upsertStrain({
      name: strain.name,
      mood: strain.mood,
      dateCrawled: new Date(),
    });
  }
```

Schema:

```
let strainSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        unique: true
    },
    mood: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        unique: false
    },
    dateCrawled: {
        type: Date,
        sparse: true
    },
  }
);
```

The the array that i am trying to add looks like this...

```
[
    {
        "name": "Blackberry Hashplant",
        "mood": "Sleepy"
    },
    {
        "name": "Walrus Kush",
        "mood": "Happy"
    },
    {
        "name": "Cherry Cheesecake",
        "mood": "Sleepy"
    },
    {
        "name": "Gorilla Cake",
        "mood": "Hungry"
    },
    {
        "name": "Divorce Cake",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Biscotti",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Kush Mints",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Cookie Dawg",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Cake Batter",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Crazy Glue",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Grapefruit Sour Dream",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Gelato Cake",
        "mood": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Garanimals",
        "mood": ""
    }
]
```

please help...been stuck on this for a while

Comment: Are you sure you have included everything in `strainSchema` ? I suspect you might have missed a field that has a unique index and defined a default value. Likely to be `_id` or `id`

Comment: Hmm I didn’t explicitly define a _id in the Schema bc i thought it was autogenerated by mongo and I didn’t need to include the Id. Do I need to explicitly define Id for the auto generated id?

Comment: Then perhaps, could you try looking for a field that has a default value set up?

Comment: No default values :/